# Can sum of first $n$ primes be represented as a weighted sum of first $k<n$ primes with weights sum to $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For the sum of first $n$ primes, denoted as $x_n = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i$ with $p_i$ representing $i$th prime, can $x_n$ be represented as a weighted sum: $x_n = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i p_i$ with $k<n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k c_i = n$ and $c_i \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$?

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z}^+$ mean $\{0,1,2,3,\dotsc\}$ or $\{1,2,3,4,\dotsc\}$ here?

Comment: The latter here, for sure.

Comment: In that case: No, cannot be done, impossible.

Comment: @DanielFischer why is that so?

Comment: What is the largest $\sum_{i = 1}^k c_i p_i$ that you can achieve with these constraints?

Comment: For the case of 2,3,5,7 I can think of 5*3+3=18 > 2+3+5+7=17 ...

Comment: But you have a $0$ coefficient in that. If you allow zeros, it sometimes is possible (e.g. $1\cdot 2 + 0 \cdot 3 + 3\cdot 5 = 2+3+5+7$). You said you exclude $0$ as a coefficient. Then the largest sum you can achieve is $\sum_{i = 1}^{k} p_i + (n-k)\cdot p_k < \sum_{i = 1}^n p_n$ since $(n-k)p_k < \sum_{i = k+1}^n p_i$.